# JMF Output Stream

Tags: java, audio, stream, jmf

Does anyone have a simple example of how to take a local file and (unicast) stream it with Java JMF?  Examples from others seem scarce.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Manager#createPlayer()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Manager.html#createPlayer%28java.net.URL%29).

```
File audioFile = new File("/path/to/audiofile.wav");
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(audioFile.toURL());
player.play();
```

Don't forget to read the introducory javadoc of the [`Manager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Manager.html) class for other hints.

Answer (score 0):

I've found http://jcs.mobile-utopia.com/jcs/26201_RTPManager.java, although am having trouble getting it to work at the moment, hence [Problems creating an RTP stream with JMF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822074/problems-creating-an-rtp-stream-with-jmf) :)